# Does "if controller" in jmeter reduces the throughput in someway?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I was doing perf-test on my apis and while trying a few things, I found out that if I put my sampler(http request) in an "if controller" that always result in true, the throughput I get is half of when I use sampler with no if controller. Why is this happening ?

The comparison in if-controller is just comparing if a random variable is greater than some threshold.

My actual use-case is obviously different but this behaviour by if-controller is affecting me.
Edit:
Here's image of my if-controller configuration.
[image]

Comment: Can you show you configuration of If Controller (screenshot) and mention which version of JMeter you are using ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @UBIKLOADPACK, added in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) reference it hold a good example of using If controller without effecting performance.

> Interpret Condition as Variable Expression? If this is selected, then the condition must be an expression that evaluates to "true" (case is ignored). For example, ${FOUND} or ${__jexl3(${VAR} > 100)}

In your case you should check the `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?` checkbox and use the following condition (without quotes):

```
${__jexl3(${breachPercent} > 10)}
```

You can also replace __jexl3 with [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function

> Checking this and using __jexl3 or __groovy function in Condition is advised for performances

Answer (score 4):

In your use of If Controller as you are not checking "Interpret condition as variable expression", your code will be executed by Javascript which will perform very badly as per warning in [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) .

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) (upgrade is highly advised), a warning explains clearly the problem:

[image: Warning]

To fix it, just replace your code using [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function and checking "Interpret...":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any test element adds an overhead so test plan with the If Controller in place will either consume more resources or execute slower in case of resources lack.

With regards to the If Controller make sure you use [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) instead of default JavaScript as each time If Controller is called JMeter evaluates the condition using JavaScript interpreter which kind of slow.

Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) If Controller defaults to interpreting condition as a variable expression which theoretically should speed things up

[image: JMeter 4.0 If Controller]

Also make sure you either use something which is resolved to `true` or use `__groovy()` function instead of JavaScript.

---

Even assuming If Controller's overhead your test throughput should not be dropping by factor of 2x so make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and double check JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU and RAM.